# same resolution with different screen size

Tags: android, image, resolution

I am trying to set image for same resolution android mobile.I have to save this images to server side and fetch dynamically on mobile side. Take a example such as we have two mobiles

1: Nexus 5x             - 2.5 * 4.5 in  -  XXhdpi(1080*1920 PX)

2: Samsung Galaxy note 4- 2.8 * 5.0 in   - XXhdpi(1440*2560 PX)

(https://material.io/tools/devices/)

Now i need to create a banner for my app then i have created image

2.5 * 2 in for Nexus 5X for XXXhdpi.

**What is the size for Samsung mobile for same image ?**

For that i have to use nine-patch bitmaps (https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) or we have another option for same

Comment: In [NativeScript Image Builder](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/), if you upload your highest image, it'll correctly give you all the others.

Comment: Thanks @SoonSantos for your reply . For image transformation i am using FFMPEG on server side. i am not understanding about size for same resolution with different size screen .